# Laravel 5.1 auto incrementing row number with pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Is there any way to get pagination pretty url or something like this in laravel 5.1?

I have 15 rows in per page. And I want to increment the row count number even on paginate.

```
<?php  $count = 1; ?>
<tr>     
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Action</th>
</tr>
@foreach($years as $year)
<tr>
    <td width="20%">{{ $count++ }}</td>
    <td width="50%">{{ $year->year }}</td>
    <td width="30%">
        <a href="{{ route('admin.year.edit', $year->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

But when I goes to next page the $count var starts from beginning. How can I get  $count = 16 and it will increment and so on?

Comment: $count = ($page-1) * 15 + 1;
for for page 1 count will be  1 and for page 2 count will be 16

Comment: it threw an error. Undefined variable: page

then I have added this $_GET['page'] instead of $page
.
And its working fine as I expected. 

Thanks you so much

Comment: ofcourse.. I just gave you the formula, replace $page with the current page number

Answer (score 12):

In Laravel 5.3 you can now use the `$loop` variable in your views. So you could do something like:

```
{{ (($results->currentPage() - 1 ) * $results->perPage() ) + $loop->iteration }}
```

in your blade templates now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
@foreach ($products as $key=>$val)
  {{ ($products->currentpage()-1) * $products->perpage() + $key + 1 }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the paginate helper method:

`$results->perPage()` -> per page count
`$results->currentPage()` -> current page number

So you can use this formula:

```
(($results->currentPage() - 1 ) * $results->perPage() ) + $count
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your first line of code

```
$count = 1
```

by below code,

```
$count = ($years->currentpage() - 1) * $years->perpage();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use :

<?php $i = $years->perPage() * ($years->currentPage() -1); ?>

@foreach($years as $year)
<tr>
    <td width="20%">{{ $i }}</td>
    <td width="50%">{{ $year->year }}</td>
    <td width="30%">
        <a href="{{ route('admin.year.edit', $year->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php $i++;?>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use pagination then try this:

```
@foreach ($noticelist as $key=>$info)
 <tr>
  <th scope="row">{{ ($noticelist->currentpage()-1) * $noticelist->perpage() + $key + 1 }}</th>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the results like this**

**Write this:** 
`<?php $i = $years->perPage() * ($years->currentPage() -1); ?>`

Before `foreach()` loop starts

**After that:** 
`<tr>`
`<td>{{ $i+1 }}</td>`
`</tr>`

**Then last step:**
Before `endforeach()` 
After  `</tr>`
Write this `<?php $i++;?>`

 **Like this:**
`</tr>`
`<?php $i++;?>`
`@endforeach`